# have vs get with subject vs object

Tags: word-choice, difference

would you please explain to me the difference between the sense, feeling or connotation of the four following sentences:

- a) I had him fix my car
- b) I got him to fix my car
- c) I had my car fixed (by him).
- d) I got my car fixed (by him)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, which I've spent a while thinking about.

The difference between the active and passive forms is what we are focusing on - the work being done, or the person doing it.

> I got my car fixed

The focus is on getting the car fixed, not on who did it.

> I got him to fix my car.

The focus is on him doing something for me, not on the car.

The difference between *had* and *got* is more subtle, and often both could be used. But I think that *had* suggests that it was something I was planning, rather than something that suddenly had to be done. *I had my car fixed* suggests that I had been driving around with a problem for a while, until I was able to arrange for it to be fixed. I would use *got* if the windscreen was smashed, or the exhaust fell off, and I needed it fixed in a hurry.

The other point, for me, is that I don't think I'd use the active *had* at all: to me that is an American expression. I'd say *I had a table built* but I don't think I'd say *I had Paul build a table for me*. Because of the "intention" thing, I probably wouldn't say *I got Paul to build a table for me* either - I'd most likely say *Paul built me a table*, and leave the listener to assume that I had initiated the process.

Comment: thanks for your helpful reply. However, American speakers use “have someone do something” very frequently. Eg, I had him answer my questions; or, I had my students do the exercises; in such cases, using a passive mode can not convey the speaker’s intention. now, what do you think is the difference between “I got my students to do the exercises” and “I had my students do  the exercises” ?

Comment: One's British and the other American?

Comment: You would not use the active had? We had the servants do it this morning. No?

Comment: No, I wouldn't. "We got the servants to do it this morning".

Answer (score 0):

**To have (get) *someone* do something**.

a) I had him fix my car.
b) I got him to fix my car.

You might try to **get someone to do something** or go somewhere by offering them something attractive or exciting in return.
[Cambridge Dictionary Blog: About Words written by an English lexicographer](https://dictionaryblog.cambridge.org/2018/04/11/prodding-and-urging-getting-people-to-do-what-you-want/)

a) and b) mean the same thing. a) is more formal:

In a report on an event:
We **had the delegates arrive** on the right side of the building.
But I might say: We **got the delegates to arrive** on the right side of the building.

These are less strong than: to make someone do something. Basically, you ask them to do it and they do.

COMPARED TO:

**To have (get) *something* done by someone**

c) I had my car fixed (by him).
d) I got my car fixed (by him).

c) and d) also mean the same thing. Again, the difference is one of formality.

In c) and d), are passive constructions. The meaning is to have **something done** by someone. I had (got) my hair cut by the barber.

But in an insurance report: He **had his car fixed** by a mechanic.