# the meaning of Have sb vs Get sb

Tags: causative-have, causative-get

some people say “have someone do something” or “get someone to do something” can mean “persuade or make or want somebody to do something” but I feel there’s some subtle difference. what is that subtle difference or feeling around them?

take these 4 ones as an example:

I had my clients do those exercises.
I got my clients to do those exercises.
I made my clients do those exercises.
I persuaded my clients to do those exercises.

what are that subtle emotional difference between them?

please note, here the subtle differences between using “HAVE sb vs PERSUADE sb vs Want sb VS GET sb” is emphasized and also the question is focused on HUMAN objects, hence its difference with the questions about “have vs get sth done”.

Comment: This seems to be very close to  your recent question https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/316198/have-vs-get-with-subject-vs-object, which has already been answered.

Comment: @JamesK this is different question, which has HUMAN as object and also containing a comparison between HAVE vs PERSUADE and MAKE which is not existing in the other question of mine. would plz help me with this question?

Comment: Note that you need to capitalize the first letter in a sentence, please edit it.